# Lonely \item - perhaps a missing list environment, missing package?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I'm trying to implement some pseudocode in my LaTeX document but I keep getting the following error: Lonely item, perhaps a missing list enviroment. The packages I'm using are:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,textcomp}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tabu}
```

And I have code looking like:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\Function{algo}{tree, iter, max\_iterations}

\State beta, gamma =    {\Call{initial\_guess}{}}
curr = np.inf

\For {i in range(iter)}
    \State old = after
.
.
.
```

What am I missing, why can't I run this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`algorithm` is a floating environment, but essentially just a block that can move around if needed. You're using the `[H]` float specifier which disallows this floating behaviour, but that's not relevant here.

Within the `algorithm` environment, you want to place your pseudocode. For that to happen, you need to use an additional `algorithmic` environment:

```
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{<caption>}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    <your pseudocode>
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

The optional argument to `\begin{algorithmic}[<num>]` numbers the line modulo `<num>`. `algorithmic` enables a *list* (like `enumerate`), with each `\State` (and some other instructions) being `\item`s within this list. Since you didn't use `algorithmic` but have `\State`s, it's like an `\item` without a list, which causes the error - "Lonely `\item`, perhaps a missing list environment".

Comment: Couldn't be more thankful, thanks a lot for this response, has been bothering me for a long time. Have a good one sir!